# loop an array to add append elements to another array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

Team, i need to loop to only add selective elements to another array.
`bazel_spa` array is not getting appended but replaced.

cant seem to append it. any hint what am i lacking?

```
bazel_paths_array=(a b c d)
len_bazel_paths_array="${#bazel_paths_array[@]}"
bazel_fpv=""
bazel_spa=()
printf "\nlength of bazel paths array is %s:\n\n" $len_bazel_paths_array

    for abp in ${bazel_paths_array[@]}
    do
        if [ -z "$bazel_fpv" ]
        then
            bazel_fpv="$abp"
            printf "\ninside loop bazel_fpv is %s:\n\n" "$bazel_fpv"
        else
            bazel_spa+=($abp)
        fi
        printf "after fi next abp is: %s\n\n" "$abp"

        printf "\nbazel_spa is: %s\n" ${bazel_spa[@]}
    done
```

output

```
length of bazel paths array is 4:


inside loop bazel_fpv is a:

after fi next abp is: a


bazel_spa is: 
after fi next abp is: b


bazel_spa is: b
after fi next abp is: c


bazel_spa is: b

bazel_spa is: c
after fi next abp is: d


bazel_spa is: b

bazel_spa is: c

bazel_spa is: d
```

expected
`bazel_spa is: b c d`

Comment: @Wiimm that's what I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76063946/1745001) about an hour earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you posted, e.g.:

```
bazel_spa is: b

bazel_spa is: c

bazel_spa is: d
```

shows that the array IS being appended to. To get this instead:

```
bazel_spa is: b c d
```

change

```
printf "\nbazel_spa is: %s\n" ${bazel_spa[@]}
```

to

```
printf "\nbazel_spa is: %s\n" "${bazel_spa[*]}"
```

so you're printing a single string made from the concatenation of the array elements rather than each element of the array individually.

I also added the missing `"`s around the array reference. http://shellcheck.net would've told you about the missing quotes there and in other places in your script.